# Finding duplicate files using Python

Tags: python, scripting

This was a question that appeared in a Python coding competition and was wondering how this can be achieved.

Problem statement:

You have two directories(with possible subdirectories in it). Your script should find out duplicate files by comparing contents of the *same filenames* in the two root directories

Result:
FAIL: If contents of atleast one same filename differs

PASS: Otherwise

Here's a sample figure

```
 /dir1                       /dir2
       -- file1                   -- file1 
       -- file2                   -- fileA  
       -- file3                   -- fileB   
       -- ....
       -- ...
       ---/subDir1
            --file1
            --file2

file1 of dir1 contains :- foo bar
file1  of dir2 contains :- foo 
Result - Fail

file1  of dir1 contains :- foo bar
file1  of dir2 contains :- foo bar
Result - Pass.
```

I attempted using hashing by file size, but it was obviously not the way :)

PS: Any scripting language can be used.

Thanks
Kelly

Comment: I was going to explain a method but I think it's better to just refer you to the complete program http://www.ssokolow.com/scripts/fastdupes.py (I didn't write it but I use a modified version of it), looking at it would be better than me attempting to explain how it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this in a tiered manner.

1. Go through each dir/subdir, compare the size of the files.
2. If the file size is different => fail
3. Compute the SHA1 hash of each file if that does not match => fail
4. If SHA1 hashes match do a byte by byte comparision of the contents
   in    the file to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Can you please provide a pseudo code? I am following the post given here but not able to get the result http://code.activestate.com/recipes/362459-dupinator-detect-and-delete-duplicate-files/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [filecmp module](http://docs.python.org/library/filecmp.html) in the standard library.

Computing hashes is not useful when each file is compared to just one other file. The entire file must be read to compute a hash, and read again to confirm a match. By contrast, a direct comparison can be aborted at first difference.